# ClassFormatError with Jsoup on Google App Engine 1.6.4 only on localhost

Tags: java, google-app-engine, localhost, jsoup

In my Google App Engine application I use jsoup library (jsoup.org).
I installed 1.6.4 SDK of GAE on Eclipse and the code stopped working only on localhost. The application on appspot.com works well and the same application works well in localhost if I use GAE 1.6.3.

The code is (for example):

```
string = Jsoup.clean(string, Whitelist.none());
```

The exceptions are:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Invalid method Code length 73191 in class file org/jsoup/nodes/Entities
```

or (when I execute the code a second time)

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jsoup.nodes.Entities$EscapeMode
```

Does anyone have the same problem? How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 3):

Check out this:
http://www.4shared.com/folder/l8tNGCef/public.html

there are 2 files:
A fixed jsoup jar that solves this problem
and the source codes

Answer (score 1):

The same happened to me after upgrading to the 1.6.4 SDK of GAE.
What caused the the exception for me was

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for answer instead of comment! (I don't have enough reputation.)
The jsoup-1.6.2-GAE.jar provided by Yoav A is very excellent but it seems to have regression issue.
The program to reproduce the regression is below

```
    String html = "<div>30&deg;C</div>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);
    System.out.println(doc.toString());
```

When the original jsoup-1.6.2.jar is used, the result is OK. When jsoup-1.6.2-GAE.jar is used, the string '30°C' would become garbled.

Comment: check out GitHub Jsoup project [link] (https://github.com/jhy/jsoup)
there is a Release 1.6.3 [PENDING] with my fix in it.
i think that version will work for you

Answer (score 0):

I think the JVM limits are about (65,535 bytes per method), so you may have to split() the long Entity class into multiple methods

Answer (score 0):

There is a patch for the 1.6.4 release to 1.6.4.1 which resolves this and other class loading and performance issues (http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7282)

Latest SDK link:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Java